# Distinct SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with the following information in a table:

```
ID  Name
--  ----
1   John
2   Jill
3   John
4   Phil
5   Matt
6   Jill
```

I want to display the unique names in a drop down list. Because of this, I need just one of the IDs associated with the unique name. I know it's dirty. I didn't create this mess. I just need the unique names with one of the ids.  How do I write a query that will do that? I know that the following won't work because of the ID field.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  [ID], [Name]
FROM
  MyTable
```

Comment: A good question is : why are there duplicates in the table ? 
Is it part of the functional requirements ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, [Name]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [Name]
```

This will return the first (i.e. MINimum) ID for each distinct Name

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with rank over function

```
SELECT
Id,
Name
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    Id,
    [Name],
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] Order By Id) As Idx
    FROM Test
) A
WHERE Idx = 1
```

To get understanding about rank over function read this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx